# How use tidyr::full_seq function into a mutate?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = seq(from = as.Date('2000-12-13'), to = as.Date('2000-12-21'), by = 2), 
  y = LETTERS[1:5], 
  w = LETTERS[2:6]
)
```

I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = (x), .fns = ~ full_seq(x = ., period = 1)))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
> x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 5.
> ℹ Input `..1` is `across(.cols = (x), .fns = ~full_seq(x = ., period = 1))`.
> ℹ Input `..1` must be size 5 or 1, not 9.

My **desired** **output** is:

```
           x y w
1 2000-12-13 A B
2 2000-12-14 NA NA
3 2000-12-15 B C
4 2000-12-16 NA NA
5 2000-12-17 C D
6 2000-12-18 NA NA
7 2000-12-19 D E
8 2000-12-20 NA NA
9 2000-12-21 E F
```

How adjust this function with `tidyr` functions and fill `NA`s with `0` in same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `complete` :

```
tidyr::complete(df_1, x = seq(min(x), max(x), by = '1 day'), 
                 fill = list(y = 0, w = 0))
```

Or with `full_seq` :

```
tidyr::complete(df_1, x = full_seq(x, 1), fill = list(y = 0, w = 0))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  x          y     w    
#  <date>     <chr> <chr>
#1 2000-12-13 A     B    
#2 2000-12-14 0     0    
#3 2000-12-15 B     C    
#4 2000-12-16 0     0    
#5 2000-12-17 C     D    
#6 2000-12-18 0     0    
#7 2000-12-19 D     E    
#8 2000-12-20 0     0    
#9 2000-12-21 E     F
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I have the follow error message: `Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, !is_complete(data[[var]]), value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`. `0` not appears.

Comment: @neves Since you are on R < 4.0.0 , you need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `data.frame` call. Or convert the columns to characters by `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.character)`

Answer (score 2):

One way to work is to join data frames:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = seq(from = as.Date('2000-12-13'), to = as.Date('2000-12-21'), by = 2), 
  y = LETTERS[1:5], 
  w = LETTERS[2:6]
)
df_1 <- merge(data.frame(x = tidyr::full_seq(df_1$x, 1)),
              df_1,
              all.x = TRUE,
              by = "x")
```